# How to find mu values in hypothesis questions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study

I'm currently taking a statistical analysis and quality control class, and we are talking about 2 sample t-tests currently. I've been having issues since 1 sample z-tests on understanding what $\mu$ actually means or how to find it. Like in a t-test.

> Did the mean compaction value in 2014 meet the target compaction
>   percentage of 4% air? Perform a 1 sample t test (by hand) to check
>   this.
>
> 2014 Compaction values = 94,
>   94.5,
>   95.9,
>   93.9,
>   95.2,
>   94.4,
>   96.4,
>   93.8,
>   95.8, 96,
>   95.9,
>   95.4,
>   95.2,
>   93.2,
>   93.4,
>   92.7,
>   97.3,
>   94.1,
>   95.4,
>   94.6,
>   95.6,
>   92.1,
>   92.5,
>   93.6,
>   92.6,
>   91.3,
>   95.6,
>   92.8,
>   96.6,
>   93.6

$\bar{x} = 94.447$

$\mu_0 = \text{Where I am having issues}$

$n=30$

$s= 1.448$

How do I find $\mu$?

Comment: If you are doing a one sample t-test $\mu_0$ is the value of $\mu$ that assume under the null hypothesis. So you must have specified it.

Answer (score 0):

This type of hypothesis test attempts to answer the question: What is the population average, $\mu$? In this case, we're asking: "Is the population average, $\mu = \mu_0$?"

The population follows some distribution, however we never get to see it, which is why we're always trying to estimate $\mu$. If we knew the distribution, we wouldn't have to estimate anything :)

We can however make assumptions on what we think the distribution is (Normal for Z test or Student T for T-test) and then run a hypothesis test to see if our observed data is reflective of a distribution with mean $\mu_0$.

In other words: If the true population distribution follows a T-distribution, say, with mean $\mu_0$, how unlikely is it that we observe this sample data? This involves calculating a T-statistic, $T$, and running either a one-tail or two-tailed test. Then look at your p-value and make a call. See [here](http://www.statisticssolutions.com/manova-analysis-one-sample-t-test/) for more details on this procedure.

In your case, we are given sample data and summary statistics such as $\bar{x}$, $s$ and $n$. And I suspect that $\mu_0 = 1 - 4\% = 96\%$ given the wording of the question and observed sample values. This is all you need to calculate the T-statistic. I'll it leave you to determine if it's a one or two tail test.